# Отправка формы xhr в wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, ajax, form

Не нашёл годного туториала по отправке формы через ajax (синтаксис нужен на vanilla js) в вордпрессе. В wp собираюсь использовать плагин wp mail smtp. Буду очень признателен за ваш код с комментариями, это поможет мне, как новичку, разобраться с темой.

```
<div class="contactus__form">
    <form class="contactus-form form" id="contactus-form" action="">
        <div class="contactus-form__content">
            <div class="contactus-form__group"><input class="contactus-form__input" type="text" name="fullname" placeholder="Your name" required="required" pattern="^[A-z|А-я][a-z|а-я]{2,}$" /><input class="contactus-form__input" type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Your subject" required="required" pattern="^[A-z|А-я][a-z|а-я]{2,}$" /></div>
            <div class="contactus-form__group"><input class="contactus-form__input" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Your e-mail" required="required" /><input class="contactus-form__input" type="text" name="company" placeholder="Company name" /></div><textarea class="contactus-form__text" name="text" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Write your message" required="required"></textarea>
         </div>
         <div class="contactus-form__footer">
             <div class="contactus-form__button"><input class="contactus-form__submit button" type="submit" value="Send messsage" /></div>
         </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Плохо искали потому что

Comment: Покажите свой js код

Comment: [WP SE: jq ajax to valnilla js xhr](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/274983/turn-jquery-ajax-request-into-xmlhttprequest-vanilla-javascript) - практически всё что нужно знать...